# mongodb database don't export from mLab cloud

Tags: mongodb, cloud, mlab

I have try to export my old mongodb database from mLab cloud, but it's show an SyntaxError. Please see my query and SyntaxError below :

query: mongoexport -h ds02575.mlab.com:25752 -d heroku_g2dn9rd9 -c accounts -u adam -p dino -file accounts.json

And SyntaxError: 2017-12-28T10:36:37.340+0600 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:15

Please tell me how can i export it, It's really important for me now

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mongoexport should be run from the [system command line](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#considerations), not from the mongo shell.